# Office.Binding - sort bindings by hierarchy in the word document (angular)

Tags: office365, office-js, office365api, office-addins, word-addins

```
                            Office.context.document.bindings.getAllAsync((result: Office.AsyncResult) => {             
                                if (result.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                                    for (let attBinding of result.value) {
                                        var binding = attBinding as Office.Binding;  
                                    }
                                } 
                            })
```

We are developing an Office app with storage with selected text. We save all selected text in bindings list. But we need sorted list by range selected text in whole document. But function getAllAsync() return random list of bingings...

How can we sort this bindings by hierarchy in the document?

For example:

Text1 (selected first)
Text2 (selected third)
Text3 (selected second)

--

and we need sorted list like:

1. Text1
2. Text2
3. Text3

Not random list!

Comment: it is possible?

Comment: Hello! interesting questions, I need some clarification though. 1) What do you mean by hierarchy? are you referring to the order in which the bindings are in the reading order of the document? (top down)  2. Not sure I understand what "save all selected text in the bindings list" so you have in your example 3 bindings? just one binding?  Is your question about getting the bindings within the selection in reading order? Please clarify so I can give better guidance. thanks!

Comment: - "are you referring to the order in which the bindings are in the reading order of the document" - yes, top->down;

- "so you have in your example 3 bindings" -> yes, I have 3 bindings ( 3 objects of Office.Binding );

I need list of all bindings which the bindings are in the reading order of the document - it is possible?

Comment: it is possible? any ideas?

Comment: yes sorry for the delay, check my answer below...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! The key here is to keep in mind that creating a binding is effectively adding a content control to the document, so  what you need to do is to use the contentControls collection applied either to the selection or the body of the document and traverse it to get the reading order. (btw not clear from your question if you need just on the selection or all the document but I will explain both).

Now a few clarifications before the sample:

1. Indeed, the bindings.getAllAsync() method does not match the reading order, but its not random either. It actually returns the bindings in its creation order, which seems not useful for your scenario.
2. On the other hand [range.contentControls](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/range) collection (range can be a selection or the body of the document) will get you the all content controls within the range in the reading order of the document. Please note that this collection will include both content controls with and without bindings. So you need to make sure when you create your bindings, that you do it in a way that you will be able to recognize them afterwards, this is simple to do since with the new API you can insert a content control, set up its title and then use the [bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/bindings.addfromnameditemasync) method to create a binding using the title. You can also setup the tag of the content control to identify in the context of your solution that this represent a binding.

Here is an example of how you can create the content controls and add a Binding to them, and then another showing how to use the contentControls collection to traverse the bindings in the reading order:

**Create Binding:**

```js
function insertContentControlWithBinding() {
    Word.run(function (context) { 
        //first we insertTheContentCOntrol on the selection, then set the title and tags and finally create the binding.
        var myContentControl = context.document.getSelection().insertContentControl();
        context.load(myContentControl);
        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                myContentControl.title = "identifier"; //this will be used later to create the binding.
                myContentControl.tag = "BOUND"; //used to mark as a bound content control.
                return context.sync()
                    .then(function (context) {
                        Office.context.document.bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync("identifier", Office.BindingType.Text, {}, function (result) {
                            if (result.status = Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                                console.log("binding Created succesfully")
                            }
                         })

                     })    
             })

    }).catch(function (e) { 
        console.log(e.message);
    })
}
```

**Get Bindings in reading order:**  This is really the bottom line answer to your question, but I thought a good explanation of what's going on will be useful. thanks for the patience!

```js
function getBindingsinReadingOrder() {
     Word.run(function (context) { 
        var myContentControls = context.document.body.contentControls; 
        context.load(myContentControls);
        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                // lets traverse the content controls and checl which ones are bound by checking the tag.
                for (var i = 0; i < myContentControls.items.length; i++) {
                    if (myContentControls.items[i].tag == "BOUND") {
                        //its a binding! lets print the content
                        console.log(myContentControls.items[i].text);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("not a bound cc");
                     }
                 }
             }) 
    }).catch(function (e) { 
        console.log(e.message);
    })
 }
```

Hopefully this add clarity and unblocks your scenario.
Thanks and Happy Coding!
Juan.